# Bit comparation macro failing on 32bit OS

Tags: ios, objective-c, 64-bit, bit-manipulation

I have a property:

```
@property(nonatomic) unsigned long availableTypes;
```

The value of `availableTypes` is `481` == `0001 1110 0001`.

I need to know which bits are on/off. So I have a macro:

```
#define isBitAtIndexOne(number, bit)       (BOOL)(number & (1 << bit))
```

When I try to get the value of the bits, everything is working fine for bits 0-7. However when I try bit 8th:

```
BOOL typeAvailable = isBitAtIndexOne(availableTypes, 8);
```

On 64bit I receive `YES` (proper value), on 32bit I receive `NO` (invalid value, should be `YES`).

I don't get why higher values are cut. The value is `unsigned long` so it should be able to store 8th bit.

-- BTW --

I've also thought that the macro is converting the value and cutting out top bit so I've tried with inline function:

```
extern BOOL isBitAtIndexOne(unsigned long number, NSInteger bit);
inline BOOL isBitAtIndexOne(unsigned long number, NSInteger bit) {
    return (BOOL)(number & (1 << bit));
}
```

But it doesn't help at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is to do with casting to `BOOL` as I suspect `sizeof(BOOL) == 1` and when you go beyond bit-7 you are out-of-range of what it can represent.

Try:

```
#define isBitAtIndexOne(number, bit) ((number & (1 << bit)) != 0)
```